# Update panel asp.net - page refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

Page url: http://advancedmedia.co.il/data.aspx

Code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="page_content_cp" Runat="Server">
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UP1" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<section id="page_section">
<div class="data_top">
<ul class="bxslider">
    <asp:ListView ID="LV_slider" runat="server" DataSourceID="**">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <li>
    <asp:Image ID="Image11" ImageUrl='<%#XPath("big_image_url") %>' AlternateText="slider"  runat="server"  />
    </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>

</ul>
</div>
<div class="shaddow"></div>
<div class="data_bottom">
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="LV_data_bottom" DataSourceID="**">

<ItemTemplate>
<div style="display:inline;">
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#XPath("big_image_url") %>' ID="LB_thumb" OnClick="lb_thumb1" ><asp:Image runat="server" ID="IMG_img1" ImageUrl='<%#XPath("small_image_url") %>' />
<asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="title" ID="bottom_label" Text='<%#XPath("title") %>'></asp:Label></asp:LinkButton>
</div>


</ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
</div>


</section>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

        <asp:XmlDataSource ID="**" runat="server" 
            DataFile="~/***/***" XPath="/Data/**/**">
        </asp:XmlDataSource> 
</asp:Content>
```

Click on the thumbs "jump" the page.

I dont want the page will "jump"/"refresh" after click on thumb. how can i do that?   Maybe i wrong on the place of the updatepanel ?

Comment: and...what's your **Question** ?

Comment: Looks like you have your entire page in the UpdatePanel, which is probably what's making it appear as if the entire page is reloading. You should try rearranging it.

Comment: It will be smart to split the updatepanel to - two updatepnels ? it will work with two?

Answer (score 6):

You can always get it done using updatepanel and microsoft ajax... but there is a better and more lightweight alternative. Use jquery to swap the main image on top when the thumbnails are clicked, without doing a page refresh.

Define a surrounding div for the imain image with id "imageBox"

```
<a href="#" id="changeImage" rel="1"><img class="thumb" src="image1_thumb.jpg" /></a>
<div id="imageBox">&nbsp;</div>
```

then,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#changeImage').click(function(){
        var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
        $("#imageBox").html("<img src='image" + rel + ".jpg' />");
    })
});
```

This is both clean and lightweight. no Microsoft ajax panel junk.

Comment: or not :( 
http://advancedmedia.co.il/data.aspx
Maybe it dont work with linkbutton ?

Comment: @Bside, it should work with any button, You will have to remov eyour asp.net button code with the pure html img and <a tag as shown in my post. let me know if it still wont work.

Comment: thanks, but i must use the asp.net button and image, and not pure html, from code behind (c#) usage.

Comment: @Bside when you are referencing your button do it using .ClientID as asp.net changes the id when it has runat="server" tag, so do this $(<%= changeImage.ClientID %>.click(function(){

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about what is your problem here, but if you want to separate the Update Panel into two you can do so.

There's an explanation on how different update panels can trigger themselves.
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers

Comment: I was trying to leave the link in the comment, but it needed 50 reputation. So I thought its ok to just leave the link here.

Sorry but I did not know this was not allowed. Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 1):

Used `AutoPostBack="false"` in listview page can't be refresh ..or used javascript to change the image

Answer (score 1):

Put `ScriptManager`.

```
<asp:ScriptManager EnablePartialRendering="true"
 ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="page_content_cp" Runat="Server">
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UP1" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <!-- bla bla bla.. -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to change the following

```
UpdateMode="Conditional"
```

With this?

```
UpdateMode="Always"
```

Answer (score 0):

Set ClientIDMode=Auto on the LinkButton.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems correct. 
Here is a sample for Update panel.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication3.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="Updatepanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</form>
```

Code Behind

```
namespace WebApplication3
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Label1.Text = "change Test 1";
        }

        protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Label1.Text = "change Test 2";
        }
    }
}
```